# How to create xib both for iphone & ipad using xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c

when I add a new file "Cocoa Touch Class" that I only could choose ipad "or" iphone 's xib. So how to create both ipad & iphone 's xib for the view class?

Comment: Search for the use of autolayout and create a universal project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a new xib file. Connect it to your class. Name it with "~ipad" extension. For example if for iphone you have ViewController.xib, name it ViewController~ipad.xib for ipad. App will automatically pick the xib according to device.

Answer (score 0):

if your application have 1 or more views but very less then i'll suggest you to work with `[UIWindow sharedWindow]` but if you have multiple view then in xcode 6 you have another option known as **sizedClasses** you'll just have to enable sizedClasses for your `viewController`
 using interface Builder but remember, you'll have to use constraint to adjust your subviews accordingly.

Thanks